# Adding Text on each bar of jfreechart bar graph

Tags: java, apache-poi, jfreechart

I want to add a text on the top of the each bar in jfree chart. I want to show some text on each bar of the chart like place name it not the data on Y-axis.How can I do it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: With neither code nor an example image marked up to show what you want, it's a bit hard to help...

Comment: [`StackedBarChartDemo1`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/samples.html) is an example.

Comment: I don't want to show values. The scenario is I have three products in three places and used stacked bar chart to compare the products in three different months I want to show place names at the top of the each bar

Comment: To get the community to help you with this problem you should do the work of providing as much of the work as you can so no one else has to duplicate that. Provide code and data that draw the bar chart to the extent that you know how to do that, and then ask how do you add the missing labels. Preferably provide both the image that your example code generates and a mock up of what you'd like the final output to look like.

Comment: Look for examples of `CategoryItemLabelGenerator` like `StandardCategoryItemLabelGenerator`; edit your question with an [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

If you want to show value of bar, then this code might be helpful

```
CategoryPlot p = chart.getCategoryPlot();
p.setValueLabelsVisible(true);
p.setVerticalValueLabels(true);
```

Comment: I don't want to show values. The scenario is I have three products in three places and used stacked bar chart to compare the products in three different months I want to show place names at the top of the each bar